# SwiftUI MVVM how to loop through data and store them inside array

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, swift5

I am using MVVM in my SwiftUI project and after I request to fetch data from the API, I want to loop through the data and store some of them inside an array, however it returns error, what is the correct method to do this?

Here is my code and data struct

MenuDetailView

```
struct MenuDetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MenuDetailViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(self.viewModel.variantGroup, id: \.self) { vg in
                /*** I Need to loop and store vg.variantGroupName into array viewModel.variantChosen, how? ***/

                self.viewModel.variantChosen.append(vg.VariantGroupName)
                // This always return error:
                // Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text(vg.variantGroupName)
                        Text(String(self.viewModel.arrVariantChoosen[0]))
                    }
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(vg.variant, id: \.self) { v in
                            Text(v.variantName)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MenuDetailViewModel.swift

```
class MenuDetailViewModel: ObservableObject, MenuDetailService {
    var apiSession: APIService
    @Published var detaildata: MenuDetailData?
    @Published var variantGroup = [MenuDetailVariantGroup]()
    @Published var variantChosen: Array<String> = []
    
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(apiSession: APIService = APISession()) {
        self.apiSession = apiSession
    }
    
    func getMenuDetail() {
        let cancellable = self.getMenuDetail()
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Handle error: \(error)")
                case .finished:
                    break
                }
                
            }) { (detail) in
                self.detaildata = detail.data
                self.variantGroup = detail.data.variantGroup
        }
        cancellables.insert(cancellable)
    }
    
}
```

MenuDetailData.swift

```
struct MenuDetailData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let idMenu: String
    let menuName: String
    let variantGroup: [MenuDetailVariantGroup]
}
```

MenuDetailVariantGroup.swift

```
struct MenuDetailVariantGroup: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let variantGroupName: String
    let variant: [MenuDetailVariant]
    let limit: Int
}
```

MenuDetailVariant.swift

```
struct MenuDetailVariant: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let variantName: String
}
```

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add this inside the `ForEach`. In SwiftUI, `ForEach` is a view. It accepts view data, it's not the same as `Array.forEach`.
You need to do it inside the view model. Like this

```
func getMenuDetail() {
        let cancellable = self.getMenuDetail()
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Handle error: \(error)")
                case .finished:
                    break
                }
                
            }) { (detail) in
                self.detaildata = detail.data
                self.variantGroup = detail.data.variantGroup
                self.variantChosen = self.variantGroup.map{$0.variantGroupName} //<--here
        }
        cancellables.insert(cancellable)
    }
```

Remove this from `ForEach`

```
 self.viewModel.variantChosen.append(vg.VariantGroupName)
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! so that is how, sorry I am very new to swift, could you maybe elaborate a little bit what is $0 means? and how to map with the nested child? or maybe is there any reading reference?

Comment: Refer to this: https://medium.com/@Dougly/higher-order-functions-in-swift-sorted-map-filter-reduce-dff60b5b6adf